# generate a string at compile time based on some condition

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, constexpr

I wanted to generate `fopen()`'s open mode parameter at compile-time (`file::get_mode()`)

```
#define CHECK_BIT(var,pos) ((var) & (1<<(pos)))

enum open_mode {
    read = (1u << 0),
    write = (1u << 1),
    binary = (1u << 2),
    update = (1u << 3)
};

template<int open_type>
class file {
public:
    constexpr static int is_read_mode() {
        return CHECK_BIT(open_type,0);
    }
    constexpr static int is_write_mode() {
        return CHECK_BIT(open_type,1);
    }
    constexpr static int is_binary_mode() {
        return CHECK_BIT(open_type,2);
    }
    constexpr static int is_update_mode() {
        return CHECK_BIT(open_type,3);
    }
    constexpr static const void get_mode(char (&mode)[5]) {
        int len = 0;
        if constexpr(is_read_mode())
            mode[len++] = 'r';
        if constexpr(is_write_mode())
            mode[len++] = 'w';
        if constexpr(is_binary_mode())
            mode[len++] = 'b';
        if constexpr(is_update_mode())
            mode[len++] = '+';
        mode[len++] = 0;
    }    
};
```

but even though everything inside the `file::get_mode()` can be determined at compile-time (as far as I can think) but i don't think it's computing at compile-time as the following code is not compiling because of the last assertion, removing the last assertion code compiles fine and runs

```
int main() {
    file<open_mode::write> f; 
    char mode[5];
    f.get_mode(mode);
    static_assert(mode[0] == 'w');
}
```

so my question is: how can I generate this at compile-time?

Comment: So, what’s your probelem ?

Comment: i don't think it's computing it at compile-time as the cl says assertion can't be computed at compile time

Comment: Your assertion checks a non-`constexpr` variable. Even if the calculation actually happens at compile-time, you have to retrieve the value in a `constexpr` way too.

Comment: constexpr static const void get_mode(char (&mode)[5])  can not be constexpr

Comment: `char mode[5]` is not `constexpr`, so it will change its values in run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char mode[5]` is not `constexpr`, so it might change its values in runtime. Instead, you could return a string literal from `get_mode()`. You should also modify the logic to prevent invalid access modes (for example, if you want both read and write, you should use `w+` or `r+`, not `wr`).

```
constexpr static const char* get_mode() {
    if (is_read_mode()) {
        if (is_binary_mode()) {
            return "rb";
        }
        else {
            return "r";
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

You can use it at compile time like this:

```
int main() {
    file<open_mode::write> f; 
    static_assert(f.get_mode() == "w");
    static_assert(f.get_mode()[0] == 'w');
}
```

Comment: making f constexpr prohibits me to use non-const functions like read and write (i wish to add them later on)?

Comment: @bluedragon Actually, this works just fine even when `f` is not constexpr. So you can add non-const functions later on. See here: https://godbolt.org/g/BVG2s4

Answer (score 3):

You're using `if constexpr` so you're using C++17.

In C++17 the `operator[]` is `constexp` so, instead of passing and modifying a C-style array, you can generate an return a `std::array`.

I mean

```
constexpr static auto get_mode ()
    {
      std::array<char, 5U> ret {}; // initialize to `\0` all chars

      std::size_t pos = -1;

      if constexpr ( is_read_mode() ) ret[++pos] = 'r';
      if constexpr ( is_write_mode() ) ret[++pos] = 'w';
      if constexpr ( is_binary_mode() ) ret[++pos] = 'b';
      if constexpr ( is_update_mode() ) ret[++pos] = '+';

      return ret;
    }
```

so you can write something as

```
static_assert( f.get_mode()[0] == 'w' );
static_assert( f.get_mode()[1] == '\0' );
```

En passant: remember to make `is_*_mode()` functions returning `bool`, not `int`.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <array>

#define CHECK_BIT(var,pos) ((var) & (1<<(pos)))

enum open_mode {
    read = (1u << 0),
    write = (1u << 1),
    binary = (1u << 2),
    update = (1u << 3)
};

template <int open_type>
struct file
 {
   constexpr static bool is_read_mode() { return CHECK_BIT(open_type,0); }
   constexpr static bool is_write_mode() { return CHECK_BIT(open_type,1); }
   constexpr static bool is_binary_mode() { return CHECK_BIT(open_type,2); }
   constexpr static bool is_update_mode() { return CHECK_BIT(open_type,3); }

   constexpr static auto get_mode ()
    {
      std::array<char, 5U> ret {};

      std::size_t pos = -1;

      if constexpr ( is_read_mode() ) ret[++pos] = 'r';
      if constexpr ( is_write_mode() ) ret[++pos] = 'w';
      if constexpr ( is_binary_mode() ) ret[++pos] = 'b';
      if constexpr ( is_update_mode() ) ret[++pos] = '+';

      return ret;
    }
 };

int main ()
 {
   file<open_mode::write> fw; 

   static_assert( fw.get_mode()[0] == 'w' );
   static_assert( fw.get_mode()[1] == '\0' );

   file<open_mode::read | open_mode::write> frw; 

   static_assert( frw.get_mode()[0] == 'r' );
   static_assert( frw.get_mode()[1] == 'w' );
   static_assert( frw.get_mode()[2] == '\0' );
 }
```

Comment: @bluedragon - yes; is `= -1`, not `{ -1 }`; with `{ -1 }` you get an narrowing error (because `-1` is negative); with `= -1` you get the bigger `std::size_t` value that, incremented, become zero; if you prefer you can initialize to zero (`pos { 0U };` or `pos { };`) and post-increment using it (`ret[pos++] =`) but, also when the compiler can optimize, I prefer the use of the pre-increment.